# How can I generate a random percentage between a defined range in C#?

Tags: c#

I'm brand new to C# and programming in general and I'm having trouble generating a random percentage from a defined range (i.e. between .5 and 1.0)

I've had success with a generating random int variables, however, my code for random percentages is not working:

```
Random r = new Random();
double percentage = r.Next(.5, 1.0);
WriteLine(percentage);
```

I'm expecting an output between .5 and 1, but I'm getting the following errors:

```
Compilation error (line 9, col 23): The best overloaded method match for 'System.Random.Next(int, int)' has some invalid arguments
Compilation error (line 9, col 30): Argument 1: cannot convert from 'double' to 'int'
Compilation error (line 9, col 34): Argument 2: cannot convert from 'double' to 'int'
```

Line 9 is referring to the last line of code I provided where the percentage variable is written. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: What does the error say? Try taking a look at the documentation for [Random.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=netframework-4.7.2).

Comment: Any time you're “getting an error” you need to [tell us what the error is](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`r.Next()` just gives you integers. But there is `r.NextDouble()`, but it gives you only a value between `0.0` and `1.0`. So you need to put it into the desired range yourself:

```
double percentage = min + (max - min) * r.NextDouble();
```

with `min = 0.5` and `max = 1.0`.

Answer (score -1):

This code works 100% for me.

```
        double one=0.5;
        double two=1;
        double Res=0;
        Random rand = new Random();
        Res = Math.Round(one + rand.NextDouble() * (two - one), 1); \\ This 1 is for rounding to minimum digit 1==> .7  , if 2==> .75 ... and so on.
        MessageBox.Show(Res.ToString());
```

^_^

Comment: your code doesn't work, `\\ ` is not a comment, and the names for `one` and `two` are terrible. Moreover the OP doesn't want any rounding. If you round then there'll be the issue of distribution: there are twice more chance that you'll get 0.2 than 0.1

Comment: First of all, double percentage = r.Next(.5, 1.0); // .5 is for the min bound and the 1.0 for the max bound.
Sorry for the comment error cos I added it form the notepad later on.
The rounding process is an optional , so you can customize it as you need.